# How to setText and save it in EditText

Tags: android

I have two EditText fields (suppose they are empty) and I will write the text there and it will be remembered there, in the sense that when I go out of the window and go back there will be text entered there. Thank you for your help :)

```
Button button1;
Button button2;
TextView devices;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.change_url);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button10);


    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            TextView buildings = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.buildings);
            String a = buildings.getText().toString();
            buildings.setText(a);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving Android Activity state using Save Instance State](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-android-activity-state-using-save-instance-state)

Answer (score 0):

As my point of view,
Store your value in shared preference and whenever you want this values get from shared preference and put in edit text.

Answer (score 0):

When you go out of a activity and you want to recover data when you come back, you should override `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)`. Inside this method you will need to save all the data you want to recover when you come back again in the Bundle.

As example for your case:

First:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  // Save UI state changes to the savedInstanceState.
  // This bundle will be passed to onCreate if the process is killed and restarted.
  savedInstanceState.putString("EditText1", mEditText1.getText().toString());
  savedInstanceState.putString("EditText2", mEditText2.getText().toString());
}
```

Then, to recover it you need to override `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)` :

```
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  // Restore UI state from the savedInstanceState.
  String text1 = savedInstanceState.getString("EditText1");
  String text2 = savedInstanceState.getString("EditText2");
  //At this point you recovered your data, so you can put in the EditText
  mEditText1.setText(text1);
  mEditText2.setText(text2);
}
```

More references at : https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html

Comment: Either it is not working or I can not implement it   :/

Comment: Do you have some error? You tried to debug it? Try to explain a little bit more, editing your post